# Open Battery Optimization Menu With All Apps Selected

Tags: android, android-settings

I am using below intent to open the app optimization settings page in Android.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
```

It opens the page but shows the not optimized apps by default. The user then has to select All Apps and only then they can find my app.

I want to show the user all apps by default. I have seen some apps do it, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? Also having this problem

Answer (score -2):

All available constants of Android Settings you can read from link below.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am still not able to figure out which one will solve my problem.